# Select files in Windows using list file with base names and wildcards

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to select a subset of (jpeg) files from a directory based on a set of base names in a list file that contains the base names.

The directory contains tens of thousands of files with names like:

```
1234_Inlet.jpg
5678-Upstream.jpg
12345_Outlet.jpg
67890-Downstream2.jpg
D0305_DownstreamFace.jpg
NBSheep6-UpstreamView2.jpg
```

That is, there is a variety of base names containing varying lengths of alpha-numeric characters, always followed by either a hyphen or underscore, then more characters, followed by ".jpg".

The list I would use to select a subset of files from this directory will contain the base names only:

```
1234
5678
12345
67890
D0305
NBSheep6
```

Can anyone tell me how to structure a batch file with appropriate looping and wildcards to select and copy a subset of files like these and write them to a new directory?

Comment: You can trivially select all files beginning with e.g. `1234` with the wildcard `1234*`. In what format exactly is the input in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%a in ("c:\somewhere\basefilenames.txt"
) do for %%b in ( _ - ) do (
    copy "c:\where\the\files\are\%%a%%b*.jpg" "c:\archived\files\folder"
)
```

For each basename (in the indicated file) and separator, copy the files matching `basename+separator*.jpg` to the target folder

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I'm sorry to be so limited in my skills, but can I run that snippet in CMD with only the obvious filename changes?

Comment: @AlexA, from command line the `for` replaceable parameters do not use the double pecent `%%a` syntax. Only one percent sign is used. You must use `for /f .... %a in  .... for %b in .... copy "...\%a%b*.jpg"`

Comment: Thank you very much for that clarification for command line use.

Comment: Thanks, MC ND, it worked like a charm once I made the adjustments you noted here for command line use.